# How do I abort fetch request and start a new one immediately?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

Here's an example from MDN below. There are two buttons. One is sending a request and another is canceling.

```
var controller = new AbortController();
var signal = controller.signal;

var downloadBtn = document.querySelector('.download');
var abortBtn = document.querySelector('.abort');

downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', fetchVideo);

abortBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  controller.abort();
  console.log('Download aborted');
});

function fetchVideo() {
  ...
  fetch(url, {signal}).then(function(response) {
    ...
  }).catch(function(e) {
    reports.textContent = 'Download error: ' + e.message;
  })
}
```

Now my case is different. I have a `query` parameter and if fetching is in progress but not finished and `query` parameter changes - how do I send a new request automatically canceling previous one?

Comment: You realise this [isn't supported on IE right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController#Browser_compatibility)? What exactly is your question? Is there a way to do that, yes.

Comment: It's supported on Edge actually @Liam + there are polyfills for IE https://www.npmjs.com/package/abortcontroller-polyfill

Comment: misread it, saw edge, didn't read on to mobile

Comment: If `AbortController` is not available, then, with judicious use of `Promise.race()`, you should be able to engineer an abortable Promise for yourself. It would act differently from passing `{signal}` to `fetch()` but the nett effect in your application code would be the same.

Comment: @Roamer the goal of AbortController is to provide cancellable requests to the fetch API, which design made it quite complicated originally ; to be able to stop a long running request (like in MDN's case, a video). Racing Promises won't help abort anything. Your user still will download the whole file even if they asked to stop the downloading. However, cancel requests are doable since at least XHR2. So if you need to polyfill it, you just have to go back to use XHR and Promisify it (with the caveat that consumer should be declared at the beginning of the request).

Comment: @Kaiido, correct, racing promises won't abort like AbortController . That's why I say "the nett effect in your application code would be the same". In other words, you can ensure that the returned promise's erorr path is taken, which is one of the desired consequences of aborting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure if I got it clearly, but from what I understand, your case is not different no.

The basics are the same, store the controller somewhere accessible to your logic that may cancel it, and cancel it if needed, before sending the new request:

```js
let aborter = null; // make the aborter accessible
function getData(param) {
  // cancel pending request if any
  if(aborter) aborter.abort();
  // make our request cancellable
  aborter = new AbortController();
  const signal = aborter.signal;
  const url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png?rand=' + param;
  return fetch(url, {signal})
  // clean up, not really needed but may help to know if there is a pending request
  .then(r => {aborter = null; return r;})
}
// first request will get aborted
getData("foo")
  .then(r => console.log('foo done'))
  .catch(e => console.error('foo failed', e.name, e.message));
// will abort the previous one
getData("bar")
  .then(r =>  console.log('bar done'))
  .catch(e => console.error('bar failed', e.name, e.message))
```

Comment: thx!! I made an [react example](https://codesandbox.io/s/abortcontroller-test-forked-4xrdy?file=/src/B.tsx) refer to yours